# How to convert a Terra rawstring into a Lua string?

Tags: lua, terra

I have some C code that returns `char *`, or `rawstring` in Terra.

How can I pass a value of this type to Lua and use it as a normal string?

If it matters, the rawstring is allocated on the heap (and I won't need to free it).

Answer (score 1):

Use [LuaJIT's `ffi.string`](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_api.html) function:

```
> terra terrastring()
>>   return "hello from Terra"
>> end
> print(terrastring())
cdata<char *>: 0x0e03c050
> print(ffi.string(terrastring()))
hello from Terra
```

And to prove it works even with non-literal Strings:

```
> C = terralib.includecstring "#include <stdlib.h>"
> terra cstr()
>>  var str = [&int8](C.calloc(4, sizeof(int8)))
>>  str[0],str[1],str[2],str[3] = 104,101,121,0
>>  return str
>> end
> print(cstr())
cdata<char *>: 0x0e03c000
> ffi = require 'ffi'
> print(ffi.string(cstr()))
hey
```

Notice that `ffi.string()` takes an optional length parameter, which may be handy to avoid using `strlen` to compute it, and that the string is interned in Lua (which may leak memory).